# How to parse GMT+-H in C++20 with std::chrono::parse

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

`std::chrono::parse` and `std::chrono::from_stream` allows us to parse many different date/time formats.

But I recently got a string like this:
`2022-07-10 22:00 GMT+2` - and I'm not sure what format should I use.

I tried:
`%F %T GMT%z` - fails
`%F %T GMT%Z` - fails
`%F %T %Z` - fails

Or maybe I just have to parse time/date and then manually get the zone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a little tricky.

- [`%T` is a short cut for `%H:%M:%S`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.parse#tab:time.parse.spec-row-26).  But you don't have a seconds field, and so using `%T` fails when the parse can't find the trailing `:` after the minutes.  Use `%H:%M` instead.
- `%Z` (parsing an abbreviation) will greedily accept [alphanumeric, or one of '_', '/', '-', or '+'](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.parse#tab:time.parse.spec-row-37) characters, and so if used will grab all of `GMT+2`.  So your use of `GMT` over `%Z` is correct.
- `%z` (offset) [requires the format `[+|-]hh[mm]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.parse#tab:time.parse.spec-row-36).  This fails for you because you only have one digit for the hours (no leading zero).  However [the modified command `%Ez` doesn't require a leading zero](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.parse#tab:time.parse.spec-row-36-column-2-sentence-3).

Putting this all together:

```
istringstream in{"2022-07-10 22:00 GMT+2"};
in.exceptions(ios::failbit);
sys_seconds tp;
in >> parse("%F %H:%M GMT%Ez", tp);
cout << tp << '\n';
```

Output:

```
2022-07-10 20:00:00
```

Note that the offset is applied and so `tp` represents a UTC timestamp.  If you instead wanted the local time, then just change `sys_seconds` to `local_seconds` and the output changes to:

```
2022-07-10 22:00:00
```

The offset is parsed, but not applied.

Comment: Thank you for a clear explanation!